# IFrame issue using google docs viewer

Tags: html, caching, iframe, browser, google-docs

I am trying to embed a PDF document using google docs viewer:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=MY_FILE_URL&amp;embedded=true" style="border: none;" height="900" width="100%"></iframe>
```

and Its working fine, but when I try to refresh the page multiple times.. sometimes IFrame content does show up and some other times It doesn't,and I get an **empty head and body** inside "IFrame " tag

- tried to set expires to: 0
- tried to add random numbers: MY_FILE_URL?var=rand() to solve some
  cash issue
- tried to add IFrame using jquery on after page has loaded

nothing seems to solve my problem..

Comment: did you ever get your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

you are not accessing the https version is the issue.
I had the same issue

change:

```
 <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=MY_FILE_URL&amp;embedded=true" style="border: none;" height="900" width="100%"></iframe>
```

to

```
 <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=MY_FILE_URL&=embedded=true" style="border: none;" height="900" width="100%"></iframe>
```

hope that helps :)